# How I can use the If coditIon for not showing some buttons to some users In Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have an array of blocked_users and now I don't want to show some buttons if a user is in Blocked_users.Here is my angualr.component.html

```
 <div *ngIf="!(userId in event.blocked_users)">
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onjoin(event.id)" >JOIN</a><br>
             </div>
```

Here the if condition is not working.So can anyone please tell how to use the if condition if we don't want to show a button to some blocked_users.Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: It will be easier for us to help if you provide your .ts file to see what `blocked_user`, `userId`, ... are like. If not I'll just ask: is your `userId` is the `id` proerpty of a `User` interface and your `blocked_users` is an array of `User`? also what is the event Object in your component like?

Comment: Ya my userId is ObjectId and blocked_users is an array of ObjectsIds of users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like:

```
<div *ngIf="!isBlockedUser(userId,event.blocked_users)">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onjoin(event.id)" >JOIN</a><br>
</div>
```

and in ts:

```
public isBlockedUser(currentUserId, blockedUserIds): boolean {
    return blockedUserIds.find(id => id == currentUserId) != undefined;
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is change detection going nuts on it. If you console log the `isBlockedUser` you will probably see a lot of calls. Better use a boolean that you compute once in the `ngOnInit` .

Comment: Okk So can you please tell me How i can do it?

Answer (score 1):

A computed property in the component class would do the trick I think.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
  <button *ngIf="isUserAllowed">My Button</button>
`
})
export class AppComponent  {
  blockedUsers = [];
  userId = 'someId';

  get isUserAllowed():boolean{
     return !this.blockedUsers.includes(this.userId);
   }
}
```

Comment: You can see an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uktife-cant-see-button

Comment: I consider that this should be the accepted answer, since you only compute the value once, unlike the currently accepted answer.

Comment: yeah i don't like noisy components or properties for that matter :)

Answer (score 0):

You should *ngIf over an object , it should be something like,

```
<div *ngIf="!event.blocked_users">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onjoin(event.id)" >JOIN</a><br>
</div>
```

Comment: No but i have ObjectIds in event.blocked_users.It is not working

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function in your component which will check if user exists in blocked_users like this

XYZ.component.html

```
 *<div *ngIf="!isUserExists(userId)">
     <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onjoin(event.id)" >JOIN</a><br>
 </div>*
```

XYZ.component.ts

```
isUserExists(userId)() {
     let result = this.blocked_users.filter(user => user.id == usersId);
     if(result.length > 0) {
        return true;
     } else {
       return false
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if `userId` is anywhere in `blocked_users`.
You should have a function in your component that check if this is true or not instead of trying to do it in your template. Your template then needs to use the result of that function in the `*ngIf`:

#### Component

```
//Returns true if the user isn't in the blocked list, otherwise false
get isUserAllowed():boolean{
    return !this.event.blocked_users.some(e=>e.id===this.userId);
}
```

*You can also use `includes` instead of some here, but Stackblitz sometimes complains about `includes` and I like comparing just the id, so I used `some`*

#### Template

```
<div *ngIf="isUserAllowed">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onjoin(event.id)" >JOIN</a><br>
</div>
```

Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dazqxq) to illustrate. Hope it helps :)